# Difference between the pairings $\text{Tr}(xy)$ and $\text{Tr}(x^t y)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the tangent space to $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ at the identity.

What is the difference between the two maps? Any subtle geometric or algebraic difference between the two pairings

$$
\mathfrak{g}\times \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \hspace{4mm} (x,y)\mapsto \text{Tr}(xy)
$$
versus

$$
\mathfrak{g}\times \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \hspace{4mm} (x,y)\mapsto \text{Tr}(x^t y), 
$$

where $x^t$ denotes the transpose of $x$ and $\text{Tr}(x)$ denotes the trace of the matrix $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most important difference is that the first one is invariant under conjugation by an arbitrary matrix $P$, while the second is only invariant by conjugation under orthogonal maps $P^t P = I$.

Comment: Thank you, and that makes sense (of course)! So the second one is an invariant if the group $G$ is a subgroup of $O(n)$ in the real setting or $U(n)$ in the complex setting, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, except that for $U(n)$ you have to change $x^t$ to $x^*$ (Hermitian transpose).